# Creating a file on an Android device

Tags: android

I am new to Android development using eclipse, although not new to software development in general.

For my first real project, I am trying to modify the example SoftKeyboard that is supplied with the SDK. I want to modify one of the keys to act as a function key, when followed by a single letter key it will enter a canned string - performing a macro function.

So far so good. I have the key and graphics modified, and found where to respond. I would like to put the canned strings in an editable Properties file stored where the keyboard can find them.

That is where I'm having trouble. It seems that I can't to create and save a file. I don't know if it's read/write permission problem, whether the keyboard (it runs as a service) is not allowed to create a file, or my code is just plain wrong.

Can someone help me out – point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much.
Barry.

Comment: Have you looked at `SharedPreferences`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are canned files that come with the APK you install to the device and only need to read (not write), you can place them in the `assets` folder of your project. Then use the resource manager to load them:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
InputStream moduleSearchTemplateIn = resources.getAssets().open("file/name/here.properties");
```

If you want to read/write files on the SD card, you'll need to add a permission to your manifest. Though, for this purpose, I'd probably prefer a SQLite table.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. These are files I create. The SQLLite table sounds like a good option.